# Converting light-year to $m\cdot y/s$

Tags: orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics, units, celestial-mechanics

For the solution to question $a$ of this problem, I'm confused with what that $3.0\times 10^8 m/s$ conversion factor is. I thought that light year is a measurement of distance, so why are we multiplying it by m/s where $s$ is a unit of time?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle unit conversion going on.
Recall that $(1 {\rm\ ly})=(3\times 10^8 {\rm\ m/s})(1 {\rm\ y})$, the distance traveled by light in one year.

By **substitution**, which may be what they meant but didn't do correctly
*[so your complaint and confusion is warranted]*
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2.3 \times 10^4 {\rm\ ly})
&=& 2.3 \times 10^4\  (1 {\rm\ ly}) \\
&=& 2.3 \times 10^4\ (3\times 10^8 {\rm\ m/s})(1 {\rm\ y})\\ 
&=& 6.9 \times 10^{12} {\rm\ (m/s)y} \\
&=& 6.9 \times 10^{12} {\rm\ m\  (y/s)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that this is a distance [in some number of meters] because $(y/s)$ is a dimensionless number.

Essentially, you are trading

the "l" for "light-" (in light-year)
for "$(3\times 10^8{\rm\ m/s})$"  in "$(3\times 10^8{\rm\ m/s})\cdot y$".

---

Another way to do this is by "fancy-multiplication by 1".
Since $(1 {\rm\ ly})=(3\times 10^8 {\rm\ m/s})(1 {\rm\ y})$,
then
$$1 = \frac{ (3\times 10^8 {\rm\ m/s})(1 {\rm\ y})}{ \rm\ ly}.$$

So, by "**fancy-multiplication by 1**"

\begin{eqnarray*}
(2.3 \times 10^4 {\rm\ ly})
&=&
(2.3 \times 10^4 {\rm\ ly})(1) \\
&=&
(2.3 \times 10^4 {\rm\ ly}) \frac{ (3\times 10^8 {\rm\ m/s})(1 {\rm\ y})}{ \rm\ ly}
\\
&=&
(2.3 \times 10^4 )  (3\times 10^8 {\rm\ m/s})(1 {\rm\ y})
\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The "fancy multiplication by 1" trick can at times be an extremely handy trick.

Comment: As can be the "fancy adding 0" trick.